# Parse cookie string in golang

Tags: cookies, go

If I get the cookie by typing `document.cookie` in the browser, is there any way to parse the raw string and save it as a [http.Cookie](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Cookie)?

Comment: Would you please why I get a -1?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    rawCookies := "cookie1=value1;cookie2=value2"
    rawRequest := fmt.Sprintf("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nCookie: %s\r\n\r\n", rawCookies)

    req, err := http.ReadRequest(bufio.NewReader(strings.NewReader(rawRequest)))

    if err == nil {
        cookies := req.Cookies()
        fmt.Println(cookies)
    }
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/TsY6RlGADT)

Answer (score 36):

A bit shorter version

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    rawCookies := "cookie1=value1;cookie2=value2"

    header := http.Header{}
    header.Add("Cookie", rawCookies)
    request := http.Request{Header: header}

    fmt.Println(request.Cookies()) // [cookie1=value1 cookie2=value2]
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/PLVwT6Kzr9

Comment: Just a note, the text from `document.cookie` and the header value `Set-Cookie` are not the same. This won't work if you're trying to parse the cookie from a `Set-Cookie` header. Mixing the two messed me up. This answer is 100% right though.

Comment: cookie with properties like `key1=value2; domain=example.com; path=/` will parsed to 3 cookies in this solution.